# What can be said about eigenvalues from the sum of elements in a row?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Here I'm struggling with my math. Now I have this question which seems unmanageable. Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, with $n\ge2$. Assume that the sum of any row is $1$. What can be said about eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$? The alternatives are irrelevant but say something like: $A$ can never have real eigenvalues or $1$ and $0$ are always eigenvalues of $A$. I can't find the relation between the sum of elements per row and eigenvalues/eigenvectors! Can someone please, give me a direction?

Comment: Observe that $(1, 1, \ldots, 1)^T$ (the column vector containing $1$ in every coordinate) is an eigenvector, with eigenvalue $1$. (Why?)

Comment: I assume you mean $M_n$, not $M_2$.

Comment: Do you mean the sum of *any* row, or the sum of *every* row?

Comment: FlybyNight, the sum of i-th row is 1, i = 1, 2, 3,...,n.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I think I completely understand the question. Here is a proof that if $k \in \mathbf{R}, k \neq 0$ is the sum of the elements of each row in a square matrix A, then $k$ is an eigenvalue of A.

Let $v = (1,1,1,...,1)$. Calculating $Av$ will result in $(k,k,k,...,k) = k(1,1,1,...,1) = kv$. By the definition, $k$ is an eigenvalue with associated eigenvector $v$.

Now, for the particular question, $k=1$ and the only information we can get is that $1$ is an eigenvalue associated with eigenvector $(1,1,1,...1)$.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

With *just* what you said, you can say that there is an eigenvalue of $1$, by writing down the corresponding right eigenvector (just a vector of $1$s). For the other eigenvalues, the best you can do is Gerschgorin's theorem, which only gives an estimate. You can say a bit more if you assume the elements are nonnegative, but you didn't say that here.

Comment: Elements don't have to be non-negative. The question is exactly the way I posted. What amazes me is how magically these things pop out. For me it is completely non-trivial and non-obvious why 1 is an eigenvalue with $(1,1,1,1,...1)^T$ as associated eigenvector.

Comment: @daniel.franzini It actually is easy if you think of matrix multiplication properly. $(Ax)_i=\sum_j a_{ij} x_j$. If x is constant then each entry of Ax is proportional to the corresponding row sum. This also has a probabilistic interpretation again in the case of nonnegative entries.

Comment: If $x = (1,1,1,...,1)$, then $\sum_{j} a_{ij}x_j$ became $\sum_{j} a_{ij}$ which is always 1, according to the question. But shouldn't it work for e.g. $x = (2,2,2,2,2,...,2)$ also?

Comment: I got it partially. For a vector $x$ be an eigenvector, it should verify $A-\lambda \mathbf{I} = \mathbf{0}$, with $\lambda$ being the associated eigenvalue, right? So, this works for $\lambda = 1$ and $x = (1,1,\cdots,1)$. Does it work for other real numbers?

Comment: Actually, it should be $(A-\lambda \mathbf{I})x = \mathbf{0}$.

Comment: Any nonzero multiple of $(1,1,\dots,1)$ is also an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, but this is the usual situation for eigenvectors.

Comment: I made some progress: given $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k$ is the sum of the elements in the $i$-th row, $i = 1,2,3,...,n$ let $v = (1,1,1,...,1)$ and calculate $Av$. You will get $(k,k,...,k)$. This proofs that $k$ is an eigenvalue with associated eigenvector $v$. Would this proof be accepted in an exam situation?

Comment: You need to be careful about notation; $k$ should be the same for all of the rows, and it's not so clear that you've assumed that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66960/discussion-between-daniel-franzini-and-ian).